# How do you explode an array of JSON string into rows?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My UDF function returns a json object array as string, how can I expand the array into dataframe rows?

If it isn't possible, is there any other way (like using Struct) to achieve  this?

Here is my JSON data:

```
sample json
{
"items":[ {"Name":"test", Id:"1"}, {"Name":"sample", Id:"2"}]
}
```

And here is how I want it to end up like:

```
test, 1
sample, 2
```

Comment: Wait, so you want it to output the JSON in dataframe rows right? So are you outputting it on an HTML website where the data is handled by JavaScript/jQuery or where do you want to output it?

Answer (score 1):

The idea is spark can read any **paralellized** collection hence we take the **string** and parallelize it and read as a **dataset**

**Code** =>

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val sampleJsonStr = """
     | {
     | "items":[ {"Name":"test", "Id":"1"}, {"Name":"sample", "Id":"2"}]
     | }"""

val jsonDf = spark.read.option("multiLine","true").json(Seq(sampleJsonStr).toDS)
//jsonDf: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [items: array<struct<Id:string,Name:string>>]

// Finally we explode the json array
val explodedDf = jsonDf.
select("items").
withColumn("exploded_items",explode(col("items"))).
select(col("exploded_items.Id"),col("exploded_items.Name"))
```

**Output** =>

```
scala> explodedDf.show(false)
+---+------+
|Id |Name  |
+---+------+
|1  |test  |
|2  |sample|
+---+------+
```